# Keep app as RC1 after installing RC2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 app. I want to install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 as well as the RC2 update but I'm not yet ready to upgrade my RC1 app to RC2.

Will installing these updates break my RC1 app? Will Visual Studio force me to upgrade to RC2?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't change the sdk > version property in global.json, you should be fine.